# API Platfrom - disabling swagger UI

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, api-platform.com

I was trying to disable Swagger UI or more precisely as I want us to provide it only for non-prod envs.

I was referencing [THIS](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/production-docs) link but, nothing is happening.

My `api_platform.yaml` file:

```
api_platform:
  defaults:
    route_prefix: '/%env(API_ROUTE)%'
    enable_docs: false
    enable_entrypoint: false
    enable_swagger_ui: false
  swagger:
    api_keys:
      JWT:
        name: Authorization
        type: header
  collection:
    pagination:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: enable_swagger: false is missing. the formats aren't configured. Are you sure you followed the turorial? Perhaps start with a blank test project first and learn with it how it's done, then apply on your main project. Normally works with less sweat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
api_platform:
  defaults:
    route_prefix: '/%env(API_ROUTE)%'
  swagger:
    api_keys:
      JWT:
        name: Authorization
        type: header
  collection:
    pagination:
      enabled: true
    
when@prod:
    api_platform:
        enable_docs: false
        enable_entrypoint: false
        enable_swagger_ui: false
```

your api_platform.yaml has look like this. Then your swagger is disabled only on your prod environment, if you use the environment properly.